# how to pass 2 parameters in Get method using java

Tags: java

My URL is like -

https://api.insideview.com/api/v1/people/abcdef?active=true

here the arguments passed are people=abcdef and active=true

How can I incorporate both the parameters using get method-

My code is like-

```
public PeopleDetailInstance peopledetail(String peopleId) {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        GetMethod method = new GetMethod("https://api.insideview.com/api/v1/people/"+peopleId);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add query parameters to a GetMethod (using Java commons-httpclient)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217070/how-do-i-add-query-parameters-to-a-getmethod-using-java-commons-httpclient)

Comment: refer this ur problem may solve http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19891494/how-to-pass-receive-multiple-args-to-a-restful-web-api-get-method

Comment: In your case url should be like this https://api.insideview.com/api/v1?active=true&people=abcdef

Comment: https://api.insideview.com/api/v1?people=abcdef&active=true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
... peopledetail(String peopleId, Boolean active) {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        GetMethod method = new GetMethod("https://api.insideview.com/api/v1/people/"+peopleId + "&active=" + active)
```

Edit - sorry by the bad format. Im in phone.

Answer (score 0):

Now sure where your api url ends but query string should be
your url + ?parameter1="value"&parameter2="value"
https://yourApiUrl?people=peopleId&active=true

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public PeopleDetailInstance peopledetail(String peopleId) {    
    URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder();
    builder.setScheme("https")
        .setHost("api.insideview.com")
        .setPath("/api/v1")
        .setParameter("people", peopleId)
        .setParameter("active", "true")
    URI uri = builder.build();
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(uri);
}
```

Comment: what is URIBuilder ? Java is unable to recognize it.